# Is there a way for scrollTop() to act when div passes instead of an amount of pixels

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For example if you look at my jquery bellow. The part `if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {` I want the "100" to be a div. So that the .test appears when the top of the div appears at the bottom of the screen. And then animates back left when the top of the div hits the top of the screen. *(I am not sure if screen is the word)*

**jquery:**

```
var $test = $(".test");
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $test.stop().animate({left: "200px"}, 1000);
} else {
    $test.stop().animate({left: "-90px"}, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use .position or .offset of the div?

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('#myDiv').position().top {
```